# Can I get Journal article resource UUID from article ID?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I have created a Liferay WCM structure with a field where the user enters the ID of an existing web content. I want to use that **ID** to [get the resource **UUID**](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/journal/model/JournalArticle.html#getArticleResourceUuid()).

How can I accomplish this?

---

#### Update:

I followed the help of *Parkash Kumar* using the **FreeMarker** language instead of Velocity and it works but using Id:

```
<#assign EntryId = 456017 /><#-- id -->
<#assign EntryArticleId= 444831 /><#-- articleId -->

<#assign articleId = EntryId?number />
<#assign articleService = objectUtil("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil") />
<#assign article = articleService.getJournalArticle(articleId) />
<#assign articleResourceId = article.getArticleResourceUuid() />
```

When I use `articleId` I get this error:

```
com.liferay.portlet.journal.NoSuchArticleException: No JournalArticle exists with the primary key 444831
```

Comment: Yes, you can get it from `JournalArticle` object by `getUuid()`

Comment: I provided you `FreeMarker` solution as you did not mention that you are using `Velocity` in your template.

Comment: They are similar.. however, each article has an `id`, a `resourcePrimKey` and an `articleId` and they are unique identifiers which consists of 6 numbers. For examply my article "Hello World" has this ids: `id=456017`, a `resourcePrimKey=444833` and an `articleId=444831`. When I use `articleId` to getJournalArticle() it doesn't work but when I use `id` it works. Why?

Comment: Do you have `groupId`? If yes, then you can use `getArticle(groupId, articleId)` from the service.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! now it works! :)

Comment: No problem, actually I didn't see the other method earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all locate `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil` using `$serviceLocator.findService` method and

```
#set($articleService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil"))
```

then use `getArticle` method to get article by id (primary key) / articleId, as following:

```
#set($id = xxx) here `xxx` is your `$id (primary key)`
#set($articleById = $articleService.getArticle($id))

#set($articleId = xxx) here `xxx` is your `$articleId`
#set($articleByArticleId = $articleService.getArticle($groupId, $articleId))
```

Now, you can access all the properties of `$article` object:

```
#set($articleResourceId = $article.getArticleResourceUuid())
#set($articleUUId = $article.getUuid())
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ParkashKumar

Comment: Welcome, happy coding!

Comment: When I use articleId in FreeMarker it doesn't work. I added an update to the question.

Comment: The error says, your database does not contain `JournalArticle` for given id.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ID you can get the UUID this way.

```
    JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(articleId);
    article.getUuid();
```